# Android Inbuild(ActionImageCapture) intent returns null intent .Cannot deliver result {who= null}

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-intent, android-camera

I am using the default camera intent to get the image in my app. The problem is camera returns null on `onActivityResult()` . The `ResultCode` and `RequestCode` are returning as expected.

My intent call is:

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1224;
....
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

OnactivityResult is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    //use imageUri here to access the image
    Uri imageuri = data.getData(); // here is getting crash 
    imageView.setImageFromUri(imageUri);
}
}
}

void setImageFromUri(Uri imgUri){
 ... TODO assign image from uri
}
```

As I put Log I got the resultCode and responseCode are not null

```
resultCode = -1
requestCode = 1224
```

Where I am doing mistake?

> But the taken picture is stored in the path (imageUri) as I specified

Is there any other way to get image using camera.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems you know the imageUri before onActivityResult. This is not correct answer but will work fine.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
```

// This image uri only you're going to use

So don't use

```
 Uri imageuri = data.getData();
```

just use the uri you known.

your code looks like this:

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//use imageUri here to access the image
imageView.setImageFromUri(imageUri); // imageUri should be global in the activity
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shadowtech this is what I did... It's working. :) You know why the intent is null?

Comment: If you remove intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri); it then you will get image in intent otherwise Intent will be null and image will be stored on URI...