# Android program saving file with (wrong) generic name, and crashing program. Thoughts on my code?

Tags: android, camera

I'm very green in the programming department. I've tinkered at this for hours and haven't gotten anywhere. Having spent much of that time trying to find solutions on stackoverflow, I'm submitting a question for the first time.

Following, I've pasted in the contents of my MainActivity.java file. 
I belive everything is declared correctly in my manifest - including permissions to write to the SD card. The bulk the the code was taken from the android API documentation. 
There are no errors to be found anywhere before running the program. I'm testing the program on a Motorola Razr Droid.

A button (rawClick) is clicked, an instance of the camera is called, I approve a picture and the program crashes. If i browse to my pictures, the picture is saved (with the incorrect file name).

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong here?

Thanks. I greatly appreciate any help you can lend.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   

// Variables
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Uri fileUri;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }    

    public void rawClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); //set intent         to use camera 

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name


    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE); // start the image capture Intent
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                         data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }       
    }



    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

}

Comment: Most likely returned `data` is null. This is a known issue on Android. For instance, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246921/android-inbuildactionimagecapture-intent-returns-null-intent-cannot-deliver-r