# Android photo cature error

Tags: android, upload, photo, mediastore

I am trying to capture camera photo in may app...
this is what I have:
The photo is saved but on the on Activity Result, I get Null point Exception.
What could I be possible missing out?

```
private Uri getImgUri() {
    File filePath= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory   (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),APP_ALIAS);
    if(!filePath.exists()){
        if(!filePath.mkdirs())
            return null;
    }
    String timeStamp= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String path=filePath.getPath()+File.separator+"_IMG"+timeStamp+".jpg";
    File file=new File(path);
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}

private void startGetPicFromCam() {

    Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri uri= getImgUri();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,MEDIA_CAPTURE_RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==MEDIA_CAPTURE_RESULT_CODE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            try{
            if(data.getData()!=null)
            Toast.makeText(this,"saved to "+data.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this,"saved to path",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, it appears I didn't read your question close enough.  It appears that the issue is that when you use EXTRA_OUTPUT, a null intent is passed back.  If you want to get access to your data, just query the file that you passed in as an extra.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246921/android-inbuildactionimagecapture-intent-returns-null-intent-cannot-deliver-r)  question for more detailed information.

Comment: I am using the code: startActivityForResult(intent,MEDIA_CAPTURE_RESULT_CODE);

Comment: are you running in the debugger? If so, for older versions of Android OS, this prevents access to the SD card which could cause your null ptr.

Comment: @VictorOdiah I've edited my answer.  Sorry, I totally goofed at reading your question the first time and missed the fact that you were using the MediaCapture filter.